# Is the square root of this Kernel still a Kernel?

Tags: operator-theory, machine-learning

I came across the projection kernel, pretty straightforward Kernel defined on pairs of subspaces (represented by the orthonormal matrices P and Q):

$K_p(P, Q) = \|P^TQ\|_F^2$

In another context, I saw this similarity measure over the same space (r is essentially a constant):

$Sim(P, Q) = \frac{\|P^TQ\|_F}{\sqrt{r}} = \sqrt{r^{-1}K_p(P, Q)}$

Is this still a kernel? I am not sure how to think about this, since the square root has a positive and negative solution, but I think in practice we are never interested in the negative solution in this case.

Comment: for future reference \| or \Vert does the double  lines without giving math processing errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone else ever comes across this: section 4.1 of "Grassmanian Discriminant Analysis" by Hamm & Lee states that the square root of the projection kernel is still a kernel.

https://repository.upenn.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1504&context=ese_papers